# How to delete the oldest directory with ansible

Tags: ansible

How to delete the oldest directory with ansible.
suppose I have the following tree structure

```
Parent Directory
 -Dir2020-05-20
 -Dir2020-05-21
 -Dir2020-05-22
 -Dir2020-05-23
```

now every time an ansible playbook is run, it should delete the oldest directory, For e.g it should delete Dir2020-05-20 in its first run if we consider its creation date to be 2020-05-20.
age attribute of file module does not seen helpful as i have to run this playbook very randomly and i want to keep limited no. of these directories.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign dirpath to the path of your "Parent Directory" where all these directories are present

```
---
  - hosts: localhost
    vars:
      dir_path: "/home/harshit/ansible/test/" ##parent directory path, make sure it ends with a slash
    tasks:
        - name: find oldest directory
          shell:
            cmd: "ls `ls -tdr | head -n 1 `"
            chdir:  "{{dir_path}}"
          register: dir_name_to_delete
        - name: "delete oldest directory: {{dir_path}}{{dir_name_to_delete.stdout}}"
          file:
            state: absent
            path: "{{dir_path}}{{dir_name_to_delete.stdout}}"
```

Comment: I want to delete the directory and not the file, with your solution its deleting the oldest file.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a recommended practice is not to use `shell` or `command` modules wherever possible I suggest a pure ansible solution for this case:

```
- name: Get directory list
  find:
    paths: "{{ target_directory }}"
    file_type: directory
  register: found_dirs

- name: Get the oldest dir
  set_fact:
    oldest_dir: "{{ found_dirs.files | sort(attribute='mtime') | first }}"

- name: Delete oldest dir
  file:
    state: absent
    path: "{{ oldest_dir.path }}"
  when:
    - found_dirs.files | count > 3
```

There are two ways to know how many files were found with `find` module - either using its [return value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#return-values) `matched` like this `when: found_dirs.matched > 3` or using `count` filter. I prefer the latter method because I just use this filter in a lot of other cases so this is just a habit.

For your reference, ansible has a [whole bunch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) of useful filters (e.g. I used `count` and `sort` here, but there are dozens of them). One does not need to remember those filter names, of course, just keep in mind they exist and might be useful in many cases.

Comment: With recurse: True its not deleting the directory saying "recurse option requires state to be 'directory'" whereas its deleting the directory with recurse: no.

Comment: Whoops, you're totally right. I was in the middle of another task and confused a bit. Sorry about that; removed the "recurse" option.

Comment: Is there any way with above code to delete the oldest directory only if the number of directories are more than certain numbers?. 
Actually now an oldest directory should only be deleted if the number of directories are more than 3.Thanks

Comment: Sure, just skipped that in your initial question. Updating my answer.